# submit job to remote hazelcast cluster

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I'm new to Hazelcast Jet and have a very basic question. I have a 3-node JET cluster set up. I have a sample code to read from Kafka and drain to an IMap. When I run it from command-line (using `jet-submit.sh` and use `JetBootstrap.getInstance()` to acquire JET client instance) it works perfectly fine. When I run the same code (using `Jet.newJetClient()` to acquire the instance and Run As -> Java application on Eclipse), I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field com.hazelcast.jet.core.ProcessorMetaSupplier.
```

Could you please let me know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of your lambda functions captures an outside variable, probably defined at class level, and that class is not Serializable or not added to the Job config when submitting from client. This is done automatically when submitting via the script.

Please see http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.6.1/manual/#remember-that-a-jet-job-is-distributed

Answer (score 0):

When you use a client instance to submit the job, you have to add all classes that contain the code called by the job to the `JobConfig`:

```java
JobConfig config = new JobConfig();
config.addClass(...);
config.addJar(...);
...
client.newJob(pipeline, config);
```

For example, if you use a lambda for `stage.map()`, the class containing the lambda has to be added.

The `jet-submit.sh` script makes this easier by automatically adding the entire submitted `.jar` file.